# Nested object from an array using lodash in typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

My Data structure reads this

`{property: ["a","b"] , value : "somevalue" , comparision : "somecomparison"}`

I want to create a object out of it like

```
{
 "properties": {
    "a": {
      "properties": {
         "b": {
            "somecomparision": "somevalue"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

What is best way to implement the nested part of it .

```
  {
      properties: {
        [property[0]: {
          [comparison]: value,
        },
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` to add the 'properties' key to the `property` array, concat the comparison, and then use `Array.reduceRight()` to create the object ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeBYAKGWQAcoB7E6MATwC5kBnMKUAcwG0BdAGkOIBucADYBXCAzggafIsgTkAtiTitGwciAbNWINoQC%20hQgpDNkMEMgC8yABQ5SFKlFo9kQsRHcLlq4OqayAYMGJgAlDYAfPxOlNQ0scQAdDDCcGAAsnAkdiTRyBwA5GTxrsAQjEXuJFzhScjJpggZdr4qahog9XIpUBAAJqJIAErAbAAWYHZ2iAg1kdZR9o4ctZIICMHh7p7iPSaa5uRYNrilLrQMHABEcDc8N%20g3XMi7IuLIDDeMShB7EBub3kSg6AS6X2QPz%207X8vxANyMBEOZjAyH6jFEwjRtksdhOEWMBFMv2EEGSwnIbDsGKxYHCQA)):

```js
const fn = ({ property, value, comparision }) =>
  property
    .flatMap(p => ['properties', p])
    .concat(comparision)
    .reduceRight((acc, p) => ({ [p]: acc }), value)

const obj = {property: ["a","b"] , value : "somevalue" , comparision : "somecomparison"}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

With lodash you can use the `_.set()` function:

```js
const fn = ({ property, value, comparision }) => 
  _.set(
    {}, 
    _.flatMap(property, p => ['properties', p]).concat(comparision),
    value
  )
  
const obj = {property: ["a","b"] , value : "somevalue" , comparision : "somecomparison"}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```